# Is it possible to create a Tkinter Window with no frame, and no background?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked through the documentation, and searched quite a bit now, and couldn't find an answer for this problem. Before I give up, I'll ask here.

I want to create a window that has no frame (as in, no titlebar, no border around the window), and maybe a transparent background. I've found how to set the background to a certain colour, but not to transparent, and couldn't find anything about whether I can have the frame not display itself.

So I ask, is it possible to create a Tkinter window that has no border, and a transparent background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No border is possible. Try something like wm transient or wm overrideredirect.

Transparent depends, have a look at the documentation for wm attributes:
http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M8 On windows you can set a transparentcolor.

Otherwise you might need a platform specific extension to create oddly shaped and transparent windows, for example: http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~fellowsd/tcl/shapeidx.html

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for an extension that can create transparent windows apart from the above mentioned 'shape'? It'll be especially nice to control the borders as well.

Comment: Maybe this helps, nothing readily downloadable comes to my mind there: http://wiki.tcl.tk/13409 ah, the shape extension can be had from: http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~fellowsd/tcl/shapeidx.html

Comment: This should work, only it's way out of my depth. The extension seems to be accessed via C, and I've barely learnt anything about C so far. Certainly, I've not learnt how to use C extensions with Tkinter. I mostly work in Python. Sorry for using up your time.